# Elephant ear weeping and yellow

Tags: houseplants, repotting

I just bought 3 elephant ear plants at a nursery. I potted them 2 days ago with indoor potting soil and kept some of their original soil. I watered them (about half a bottled water each) and they started dripping from the tips. I read that could be too much water so I barely watered them and I see one leaf is turning yellow. I have hread that yellow means it needs more water, but why is it dripping water as well? They are in part shade and part sun when the sun moves in my home.
I have them in pretty large pots I would say. Can someone please help me determine why they are weeping and why the yellowing? 
Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you add a photo or two please? Are the plants indoors or outside currently? If outside, what part of the world are you in?

Comment: You can't over-water an elephant ear; they love bogs and become invasive .Also light requirements are very flexible. Maybe transplant shock since it has been 2 days. I see an occasional yellow leaf in the elephant ears invading my pond area, I doubt it is significant.

Comment: @blacksmith37 no answers in comments, please! I will leave yours for a bit, in case you want to do some copy-paste.